# error massage "forward massage needs override" warning "module is pass dependent - compitability pass was done""

Tags: assembly, macros, x86-16, tasm

error massage "forward massage needs override(24) [in the file input]" warning "module is pass dependent - compitability pass was done [main file line 31]""
my code is:

```
file: input
enter_char proc ;; the ouput from console is saved in al; destroys ax.
    mov ah, 01h
    int 21h
    ret
enter_char endp

enter_notFullPos proc
    mov bx, 0
    mov cl, 0
    num_enter:
        call enter_char
        cmp al, "."
        jnz after_point
        mov cl, 1
        after_point: 
            sub al, "0"
            jc end_input
            cmp al, 10
            jnc end_input
            adding_number:
                mult bx, 10
                add bl, al
                cmp cl, 0
                jnz after_add
                inc cl
                after_add:jmp num_enter
    end_input:
        mov angel, bx
        dec cl
        mov pivot, cl
        ret
enter_notFullPos endp
```

and in the file: " mathop.asm "

```
mult macro num1, num2 ; returns result in num1
    push dx
    push ax
    push bx
    mov ax, num1
    mov bx, num2
    mul bx
    pop bx
    mov num1, ax
    pop ax
    pop dx
endm
```

there are 3 problems:
1. the error
2. and the program falls.
3. the program doesn't work properly

the program without the line " call downLine" doesn't shut down" 
but let's focus on the main problem that might be related to the other problems, the error.
the mult macro is supposed to put the final value of the calculation in num1, and not change any of the registers.
my main code doesn't use the macro.
and I am using tasm, with /m

my main: 
(starts at line 13)

```
assume cs:cseg, ds: dseg
include print.asm
include input.asm
include mathop.asm
    start:
        mov ax, dseg
        mov ds, ax
        print massage1
        call downLine
        call enter_char
        mov trigo_func, al
        print massage2
        call enter_notFullPos
        mov bx, angel
        push bx
        ;call print_num
        int 3h
cseg ends
end start
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qGl4.png)

Comment: You aren't even using the macro, or if you are, you forgot to show it. In general, to get rid of such an error you should use the `/m` command line switch (assuming you are using `tasm` that you also forgot to specify.) Please provide a [mcve] which also includes the exact command used.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I updated my question. what do you mean /m command line switch? where should I use it?

Comment: You did not show the command you used. You should add the `/m` to the command line for `tasm`.

Comment: As long as you never use that macro with `ax` or `bx` as the 2nd operand, I think it should work.  It looks over-complicated and harder to verify than just working around `mul` semantics normally, though.  Use a debugger to single-step your code.

Comment: do you have an idea what can be the problem that causes: “forward massage needs override(24) [in the file input]”

Comment: You did not show the code that produces the error. How are we supposed to guess? It may be a simple typo since it should normally be called "message".

Comment: I wrote the entire information presented in the error, but if it helps I attached a picture of the errors, the message is a name of one of my variables.

Comment: Eh, the error message says forward **reference** needs override. Assuming line 24 is the `jnz after_add` then maybe your version of tasm (that you again forgot to specify) doesn't like `after_add:jmp num_enter` all on one line, or the missing space after the `:`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the problem, after changing it the warning stays the same. sorry on the lack of specification, where could I see which tasm version I'm using? this bin library was given to us straight from our professor, I don't understand a lot about assembly version and what information is relevant. (the command looks like:    after_add: (enter)
     jmp num_enter now in the code)

Comment: The first line tasm should print its version info, at least mine does: `Turbo Assembler Version 2.0`. Anyway, did you check the `jnz` is actually the line 24? Does it work if you remove that line for testing purposes?

Comment: Ok I removed the line, the errors change, now I think we are getting somewhere, the errors are: symbol redefined or move between passes: AFTER_ADD then the same errors for END_INPUT and START. even though I don't have these labels defined in any other place in the code

Comment: Did you maybe `include` it multiple times? Or assembled it separately even though it is included in main hence should not be assembled?

Comment: the code shown is all the include lines I have and no, I only assembled the main. before the mult and the enter_notFull, the code worked properly, with the same file configuration. the warning from the question is still the same, I hope they are related... hopefully we are close to figure this out.

Comment: `input` needs the `mult` from `mathop` but it is included later. Try swapping the order.

Comment: it solved the problem, you want to answer the question? for the points? (I am ashamed, my main language is c, I am experienced with the importance of functions order)

Comment: Presumably "massage" is a typo for message in your title?  Copy/paste your error messages so you at least make sure you don't have typos in it.

Answer (score 0):

The peoble was in the order of the file inclusion. I neede some functions from one file in the other but they still weren't defined